# What exactly is an entity Group in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've already read the google app engine java documentation on entity transactions, cross-group transactions etc. Maybe I'm thinking much to complicated but i just don't get through -> What is an entity group?
If I have a DEPARTMENT and this department has different EMPLOYEES, is EMPLOYEE one group and the DEPARTMENT another one. Or is an entity group just a pseudo name for a group of entities that have some ancestor-child realtionships?

Was there something right in what i said?

Cheers
Oskar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is an entity group just a pseudo name for a group of entities that
>   have some ancestor-child realtionships?

There's a little more to it, but that's the basic concept. In order to organize and access data efficiently the datastore bundles entities into groups. This will affect the way you perform some queries but it's usually transparent. The only limitations you should consider for regular transactions are:

1. All the data accessed by a transaction must be contained in at most
   25 entity groups.
2. If you want to use queries within a transaction, your data must be organized  into entity groups in such a way that
   you can specify ancestor filters that will match the right data.
3. There is a write throughput limit of about one transaction per
   second within a single entity group. This limitation exists because
   Datastore performs masterless, synchronous replication of each
   entity group over a wide geographic area to provide high reliability
   and fault tolerance.